# Close current window from code behind

Tags: java, swing

I know I can close an application using `System.exit(0);` but I want to close just the current window, not the whole application. How can I close just the current window from code behind?

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

You can call [`setVisible(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) or [`dispose`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29).

Comment: i try boath solutions but windows is still opened. i want to close window when i am already inside it.

Comment: if (!instParam.equals("1")) {                 
            setVisible(false); 
   dispose();
        }

Comment: i use this inside public void jbInit() throws Exception {

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple. use dispose() if you are going to create a new instance of the dialog or form next time you will use it and setVisible(false) in order to just hide it for a while and setVisible(true) whenever you want to show it again.

This code is a sample of the latter case, from a JDialog:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // OK Button pressed
    rowId = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    setVisible(false);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Cancel Button pressed
    rowId = -1;
    setVisible(false);
}
```